# Assigning numpy array elements through predefined array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, slice

I have arrays `newx` and `newy` with size `nx*ns` and `ny*ns` respectively where `nx!=ny`.
I want to be able to set the elements defined by `newx` and `newy` in array `f` by:

```
f = np.zeros([nx,ny,ns])
for s in range(ns):
    f[newx[:,s],newy[:,s],s] = s
```

Unfortunately this gives an error:

```
ValueError: shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape
```

I understand the error but for the life of me can't figure out the correct syntax. plz help out.

**Edit:** provided sample code:

```
import numpy as np

newx = np.array([[0,1],
                 [1,2],
                 [2,3],
                 [3,0]])
newy = np.array([[0,1],
                 [1,2],
                 [2,0]])

f = np.zeros([4,3,2])
for s in range(2):
    f[newx[:,s],newy[:,s],s] = s
```

Comment: Show us complete working code.

Comment: newx and newy don't make any sense. If you want to set to s the elements at some coordinates, you should have that number of x,y,s triplets rather than a different number of x,s and y,s pairs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

newx and newy must have the same shape , so you must reshape them.

```
f = np.zeros([4,3,2])

newX = newx.reshape(8,1)
newY = newy.reshape(6,)

for s in range(2):
    f[newX , newY ,s] = s


print f
```

Comment: Ok got it, your tip that the newx and newy should be the same size was the solution. thx

Comment: Or better yet: `np.tile(np.arange(2),(newx.shape[0],newy.shape[0],1))` will give the same result.